# Umbraco XSLT Search by selected keyword checkbox

Tags: xslt, search, umbraco, keyword, checkboxlist

I've created a keyword's property type using the textbox multiple data type.

The keywords are then seperated into a list of words or phrases seperated by commas.

I've wrapped the keywords in A tag with the href linking to my search page, and including the value of the keyword so that all nodes with the same keyword will display in my search.

I want to add an option where a user can select from checkboxes with the value of the keyword, and submit a search so all checked keywords are included in the search.

[image]

I need help with figuring out how to get the checked values of the list of keyword checkboxes to submit and display the results on my seach page.

Here is what I have so far, which doesn't submit and I can't find where to add the values of the checkboxes:

```
<xsl:if test="string($currentPage/keywords) != ''">

<!-- get the contents of the textbox multiple, with commas -->
<xsl:variable name="textWithBrs" select="umbraco.library:ReplaceLineBreaks($currentPage/keywords)"/>

<!-- replace commas with pipes so you can use Split -->
<xsl:variable name="textWithPipes" select='umbraco.library:Replace($textWithBrs, ", ", "|")'/>

<!-- split into an array of items and output as unordered list -->
<xsl:variable name="items" select="umbraco.library:Split($textWithPipes, '|')"/>
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/value">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" keyword="{.}" id="{.}" name=""/>
      <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href"> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">/imagery/image-search.aspx
      <![CDATA[?]]>
      search=</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="." /> </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title"> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/> </a> </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearchBottom" name="" onclick="location.href='/imagery/image-search.aspx?search=otbra'" />
</xsl:if>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, JV

I've made some edits and now have it semi-working. However my Umbraco template has a form wrapping my content. Which I think is what is causing some issues.

In my testing I've had a form wrapping my XSL code. When I click on the "submit" button nothing happens, but if I have a duplicate of the same code the second list of checkboxes will be able to submit. Also when I make multiple selections the search results try to look for "one,two" which don't return any results (/image-search.aspx?search=one&search=two). It should search for "one two" (/image-search.aspx?search=one%20two).

My code with the repeated form:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <form name="input" action="/imagery/image-search.aspx" method="get">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$items/value">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="search" value="{.}"/>
          &nbsp; <a href="/imagery/image-search.aspx?search={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(.)}" title="{.}"> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </a> </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form name="input" action="/imagery/image-search.aspx" method="get">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$items/value">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="search" value="{.}"/>
          &nbsp; <a href="/imagery/image-search.aspx?search={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(.)}" title="{.}"> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </a> </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then I tried the following code, which didn't require to wrap the list in a form. Again multiple selections don't work, but also the only result returned is the first input value in the list (in this case 'one').

```
<ul id="checkboxes">
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/value">
    <li>
      <input id="{.}" type="checkbox" name="search" value="{.}"/>
      &nbsp; <a href="/imagery/image-search.aspx?search={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(.)}" title="{.}"> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </a> </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
<input name="searchbutton" class="button" value="Search" type="reset" onClick="location.href='/imagery/image-search.aspx?search=' + $('#checkboxes input').attr('value')" />
```

So I need help with which option to use, and how to include multiple selections in the search result.

Comment: Is there a reason why your `<input type="checkbox">` do not have a name? Form fields without a name will not be submitted. Also, what is the reason that you added an "onclick" event handler on the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes

- You seem to be unaware of attribute-value-templates. They replace the need for `<xsl:attribute>` in most cases. Use curly braces to evaluate expressions in attributes.
- Always (!) URL-encode values that you put into an URL. Compare tha `<a href="...">` below.
- When a form field does not have a name, its value will not be submitted by the browser. An ID on the other hand is not necessary.
- Using `<xsl:if test="string($anything) != ''>` is not necessary. A non-empty string is truthy, so `<xsl:if test="$anything">` is sufficient.
- Don't use `onclick` in the submit button if you want your form to transmit. Use the `<form action="...">` parameter to determine where form values should be transmitted to. Or use JavaScript, but completely avoid inline script handlers like `"onclick"`. There should be no JS in your markup at all.

XSL code

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/keywords">
  <xsl:variable name="textWithBrs" select="
    umbraco.library:ReplaceLineBreaks($currentPage/keywords)
  "/>
  <xsl:variable name="textWithPipes" select="
    umbraco.library:Replace($textWithBrs, ', ', '|')
  "/>
  <xsl:variable name="items" select="
    umbraco.library:Split($textWithPipes, '|')
  "/>
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$items/value">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="true" keyword="{.}" name="keywords"/>
        <a href="/imagery/image-search.aspx?search={umbraco.library:UrlEncode(.)}" title="{.}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearchBottom" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomalek I've made some edits with the help of your code

Comment: @JV10 In your changed code you're still using an onclick attribute in the submit button. I told you twice that this is nonsense. Why do you keep doing it?

Comment: @Tomalek I'm trying to find the best method for searching keywords via multiple checkbox options. With my page content already wrapped in a form, would using an onclick attribute not work? Should I have a form inside a form? And how do I have the search display multiple selections, from the checkbox list.

Comment: @JV10 No, nested forms are not possible. You can either create two separate forms and use CSS to position them on the page (easier + straightforward) - or you use JavaScript to send the checkboxes (more complex). Using JS works, but not the way you tried it. How to send a form with JS is a popular topic on Stack Overflow, just search for it.